# Check For String Rotation in Python

Tags: python

```py
def isRotation(s1, s2):
    return len(s1) == len(s2) and s2 in s1*2
isRotation("ABCD", "CDAB")
>> True
```

The code above was given as one of many ways to check if two strings are a rotation of each other.
However, I don't understand why String1(s1) has to be multiplied by 2 in the code.

Comment: Well it is actually quite simple. In python `str * 2` will just add a second copy of the string so `"ABC" * 2 -> "ABCABC"`. From there, it can check if the original string is a substring of this string.

Answer (score 3):

In python, multiplying strings is repeating the string, for example:

```py
>>> 'abc'*2
'abcabc'
>>> 'abc'*4
'abcabcabcabc'
```

So in order to know if a string is a rotation of another string, you would need to multiplie it by 2, for example:

```py
>>> 'bca' in 'abc'
False
>>> 'bca' in 'abc' * 2
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying a string by 2 will double the original string. And because `s1` wraps around, regardless of its starting position the whole string can be found somewhere within twice its length

```
ABCDABCD
|||| DABC
||| CDAB
|| BCDA
| ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotating a string is as good as chopping it at point of rotation and putting that chopped part at the end of string.

ABCDEFGH rotated 4 places to left is:

1. Chop at 4-> ABCD EFGH
2. Place at the end -> EFGHABCD

Python str*x gives you str concatenated to itself x times.

```
>>> a = 'String'
>>> a*2
'StringString'
>>>
```

Putting these two points together with the fact that any string can be rotated by maximum amount equal to its length (when it becomes the original string) gives you the logic to check the rotated string's presence in str*2.

Answer (score 0):

Here when we multiply `s1` with `2`. It returns `s1s1` like if `s1="ABCD"`, it will return `"ABCDABCD"`, and in if s2 in s1*2 we are checking that if `"CRAB"` is in `"ABCDABCD"` which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding of your question is- To compare a string with the rotation string.

My approach to address the same would be.

1- To get the rotation string.

```
def rotate_str(strg, n):
    return strg[n:] + strg[:n]

length = 2 #can change this to whatever value suits to you or even pass this as arg.
print(rotate('SAMPLE', length))
```

2- compare strings.

```
   str1 = 'SAMPLE'
   str2 = rotate(str1, length)
   def compare_str(str1, str2):
       return str1 == str2
```